# How can I play an audio when my tensorFlow lite android model has reached a certain confidence % of a particular label

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, kotlin, tensorflow-lite

I am working on an Android App which utilises the TensorFlow lite Model to predict some Images. The problem I am facing is that, I want to play an audio file based on the highest percentage of the label.

**Eg->** If the confidence % of label 'x' is **>=90** **then 'xyz.mp3'** from my raw folder should be played.

I have tried several methods of doing this, but I am unable to achieve it.

I am attaching few excerpts of my MainActivity.kt file for reference

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Request camera permissions
        if (allPermissionsGranted()) {
            startCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this, REQUIRED_PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS
            )
        }

        // Initialising the resultRecyclerView and its linked viewAdaptor
        val viewAdapter = RecognitionAdapter(this)
        resultRecyclerView.adapter = viewAdapter

        // Disable recycler view animation to reduce flickering, otherwise items can move, fade in
        // and out as the list change
        resultRecyclerView.itemAnimator = null

        // Attach an observer on the LiveData field of recognitionList
        // This will notify the recycler view to update every time when a new list is set on the
        // LiveData field of recognitionList.
        recogViewModel.recognitionList.observe(this,
            Observer {
                viewAdapter.submitList(it)
            }
        )

    }
```

```
  override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy) {

            val items = mutableListOf<Recognition>()
            val tfImage = TensorImage.fromBitmap(toBitmap(imageProxy))
            val outputs = flowerModel.process(tfImage)
                .probabilityAsCategoryList.apply {
                    sortByDescending { it.score }
                }.take(MAX_RESULT_DISPLAY)

            for (output in outputs){
                items.add(Recognition(output.label,output.score))
                currency = output.label.toString()
            }
            // Return the result
            listener(items.toList())

            // Close the image,this tells CameraX to feed the next image to the analyzer
            imageProxy.close()
        }
```

Any Help?